# (C++) terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I keep getting an error of bad memory allocation. I've spent the whole night trying to find where I went wrong but I can't figure out what.

I've combed through every line but still nothing. Could it be that my program/laptop just isn't strong enough?

Any help would be extremely helpful. My head is ringing and I need some rest.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

// struct to store word + count combinations
struct wordItem{
    string word;
    int count;
};

void getStopWords(char *ignoreWordFileName, vector<string>& _vecIgnoreWords);

bool isCommonWord(string word, vector<string>& _vecIgnoreWords);

void printTopN(wordItem wordItemList[], int topN);

void doubleArray(wordItem wordItemList[], int size);

int getTotalNumberNonCommonWords(wordItem wordItemList[], int size, int wordCount);

const int STOPWORD_LIST_SIZE = 50;

// ./a.out 10 HW1-HungerGames_edit.txt HW1-ignoreWords.txt
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    vector<string> vecIgnoreWords(STOPWORD_LIST_SIZE);

    // verify we have the correct # of parameters, else throw error msg & return
    if (argc != 4){
        cout << "Usage: ";
        cout << argv[0] << " <number of words> <filename.txt> <ignorefilename.txt>"<< endl;
        return 0;
    }

    //Set vector with stop words
    getStopWords(argv[3], vecIgnoreWords);

    //initialize struct array
    int aSize = 100;
    wordItem *theStructArray = new wordItem[aSize];
    int counter = 0;
    int doubleCount = 0;

    //read main txt file
    ifstream inFile(argv[1]);

    if(inFile.is_open()){
        string line;
        string theWord;

       //extract words from file
        while(getline(inFile, line)){
            istringstream iss(line);

            //extract and analyze word
            while(iss >> theWord){
                if(!(isCommonWord(theWord, vecIgnoreWords))){
                    bool inStructArray = false;
                    int inStructPosition;

                    //search for word in Struct array
                    while (inStructArray == false){
                        for(int i=0; i<aSize; i++){
                            if (theWord == theStructArray[i].word){
                                inStructArray = true;
                                inStructPosition = i;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    //if word is in struct array
                    if (inStructArray == true){
                        theStructArray[inStructPosition].count++;
                    }

                    //else if it isn't
                    else{
                        //create new wordItem and add into struct                           
                        wordItem newWord;
                        newWord.word = theWord;
                        newWord.count = 1;

                        theStructArray[counter+(100*doubleCount)] = newWord;
                        counter++;
                    }

                    //if struct array hits maximum amount of elements,
                    if (counter == (aSize-1)){
                        doubleArray(theStructArray, aSize);
                        counter = 0;
                        doubleCount++;
                        aSize +=100;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        inFile.close();
    }

    //Bubble sort masterArray
    int bI, bJ, flag = 1;
    wordItem bTemp;

    for(bI=1; (bI <= aSize && flag); bI++){
        flag = 0;
        for(bJ=0; bJ<aSize; bJ++){
            if(theStructArray[bJ+1].count > theStructArray[bJ].count){
                bTemp = theStructArray[bJ];
                theStructArray[bJ] = theStructArray[bJ+1];
                theStructArray[bJ+1] = bTemp;
                flag = 1;   
            }
        }
    }

    //Print topN words
    printTopN(theStructArray, atoi(argv[1]));

    //print others
    cout << "#" << endl;
    cout << "Array doubled: " << doubleCount << endl;
    cout <<"#" << endl;
    cout << "Unique non-common words: "<< (aSize-100+counter)<<endl;
    cout << "#"<<endl;
    cout <<"Total non-common words: "<< getTotalNumberNonCommonWords(theStructArray, aSize, counter)<<endl;

    return 0;
}

void getStopWords(char *ignoreWordFileName, vector<string>& _vecIgnoreWords){

    ifstream inFile(ignoreWordFileName);

    if(inFile.is_open()){
        int a = 0;
        string line;

        while(getline(inFile, line)){
            _vecIgnoreWords.insert(_vecIgnoreWords.begin() + a, line);
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
    return;
}

bool isCommonWord(string word, vector<string>& _vecIgnoreWords){

    for(int i=0; i<STOPWORD_LIST_SIZE; i++){
        if(word == _vecIgnoreWords.at(i)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void printTopN(wordItem wordItemList[], int topN){

    cout << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<topN; i++){
        cout<< wordItemList[i].count << '-' << wordItemList[i].word << endl;
    }
    return;
}

void doubleArray(wordItem wordItemList[], int size){

    wordItem *tempArray = new wordItem[size+100];

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        tempArray[i] = wordItemList[i];
    }

    delete [] wordItemList;
    wordItemList = tempArray;

}

int getTotalNumberNonCommonWords(wordItem wordItemList[], int size, int wordCount){

    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<(size-100+wordCount); i++){
        total+=wordItemList[i].count;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Do you know which line of your program cause the exception?

Comment: "Could it be that my program/laptop just isn't strong enough?" What do you mean by that? Have you tried checking how much memory you want to allocate, and tried a trivial `void main(…) { malloc(…); }`? Have you checked with valgrind? Also, please read and follow [How to create a *Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also `doubleArray` is not going to work.  It makes a copy of the pointer, you need to pass it by reference.

Comment: Fyi, `theStructArray[bJ+1]` in your bubblesort will ultimately access out-of-bounds on the last iteration of each inner loop. And the outer loop limits are wrong as well. That alone invokes undefined behavior. I'm sure there's more in here. You need to run this code  **in a debugger**.

Comment: Why the mixture of `vector` and manual memory management?

Comment: 'My head is ringing and I need some rest' - so you guys go and solve the problems with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing very bad things in `void doubleArray(wordItem wordItemList[], int size)`

you can call `delete []` on the array if you pass an array, but you cannot change its value, so `doubleArray(theStructArray, aSize);` will cause `theStructArray` to be deleted but not assigned to the memory you allocated.  You are just assigning the local variable in the function `doubleArray`

It is similar to:

```
void doubleit(int x)
{
   x *= 2;
}

int y=3;
doubleit(y);
```

here `x` was momentarily doubled to 6, but `y` never changed.

you need to use references, or better make `theStructArray` a `std::vector` and be done with it.